# How does "Angry birds backup" app work?

Tags: backup, angry-birds

"Angry Birds Backup" seems to be a third party app that modifies other application's data.

This should not be possible from security point of view, as it enables you to create malicious software.

So how does that backup program work?

It works on my nexus one, but phone is not rooted.
Application only asks for the network and sd card access. the former could be required for ads only (have not checked the paid version yet)

Comment: Not a dupe, but for reference, here's a previous question on backing up Angry Birds data that mentions that a phone user wanting to do this themselves would need root http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5301/how-does-angry-birds-backup-app-work

Comment: Does AngryBirds save state on a file on the SD card?  If yes, that could be why...  Otherwise if it is using a database or similar, it would be breaching a security issue (unless you were rooted).

Comment: Even if it just saved the state, how would it restore the state without root access?

Comment: @Matt Writing to / reading the SD card doesn't require root.

Comment: I realize that.  If Angry Birds doesn't make any provision for backing up and storing state data on the SD, how would a 3rd party app be able to over ride the Angry Birds state without over writing the information that I assume is stored somewhere in the /data/ directory (which you do need root to access)?

Comment: I should clarify that I'm assuming that Angry Birds data is stored in a root directory because after I wiped my phone and reinstalled Angry Birds I had to start all over, where as all the other apps that stored user information on the SD card picked up right were I left them.

Comment: @Matt Oh, sorry, I misunderstood.  I've always backed it up with Titanium, I guess I assumed the data was on the SD card with the app.  But I just checked and it's in /data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files/

Answer (score 2):

[According to the Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), files written to the internal storage such as the Angry Birds data cannot be accessed by other applications by default.  I'm guessing that Rovio used MODE_WORLD_READABLE instead of the default, however.  Maybe this was a mistake or maybe they plan on having future apps being able to read your progress and unlock sometihng, or whatever.

Of course, this doesn't bar the possibility that an Android exploit is being used to bypass the file privacy, but who really knows besides the author of the backup app?